# How to iterate through and compare values of data frames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, weather

I want to iterate through and compare the values in two data frames,`PORResult`, `p90Result` and then update the values in a third data frame, `CountResult` based on that comparison. If the value in `PORResult` is greater than the value in `p90result` I want to update the value in `CountResult` to be = 1. All of the data frames are the same size (121x365) and have the same column names and indexes. This is where I'm stuck:

```
for index, row1 in PORResult.iterrows():
    for index, row2 in p90Result.iterrows():
        if PORResult.loc[index,row1]>p90Result.loc[index,row2]:
            CountResult.at[index,row1]=1
```

When I try this I get the following error message: "None of [Float64Index([ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,\n              ...\n               nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan, 46.0],\n             dtype='float64', name='day', length=365)] are in the [columns]" I'm not sure where to go from here. Does this mean that my data frames are set up incorrectly or am I not executing the loop properly? I'm new to python so any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the reason you use CountResult.at()? It is used if an element in the dataframe is itself a list.

Comment: What I want in the end is a third data frame, `CountResult` filled with 0s if `PORResult` is less than `p90Result` and 1s where it is greater. Ahead of the loop I created `CountResult` and filled it with all zeros. I was trying to use `CountResult.at()` to update the values in `CountResult` that correspond to where `PORResult` is > `p90Result`

Comment: Doing CountResult.loc(...) doesn't resolve the problem?

Comment: I get the same error when I use `CountResult.loc()`

Comment: Could it be because I have Nan values?

Comment: What if you use iloc in all cases?

Comment: If I switch to iloc in all cases I get an error of too many indexers

Answer (score 1):

This is how I was able to resolve the problem

```
for day in PORResult.columns:
    for year in PORResult.index:
        tmax = PORResult.loc[year, day]
        perc = p90Result.loc[year, day].values[0]
        if tmax > perc:
            CountResult.loc[year, day] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop compares all the rows of the first dataframe with all the rows of the second dataframe. You should make loop such as  `for i in range(PORResult.shape[0]): for j in range (PORResult.shape[1]):`